# Conformal map of a doubly connected region to an annulus

Tags: mapping-class-groups

Hi. I am a Mechanical Engineering student. I'm not good at complex variable theory and having problem with finding conformal mapping of a doubly connected region to an annulus (or vice versa).

I know that the annulus is bounded by two circles with inner radius **r** and outer radius **R**  and the inner and outer radii are not independent and the ratio **R/r** must be determined uniqely by the doubly connected region.

My doubly connected region is actually a hollow shape in which the inner and outer boundaries are geometrically similar and concentric. Parametric shape functions of the inner and outer boundaries in **x-y** plane are expressed as: **{X=F(theta), Y=G(theta)}**.

I would be really thankful if you could help me over this issue or introduce to me some useful references.

B.G.B

Comment: What is the point of asking the same question three times?

Answer (score 1):

Nick Trefethen is the world expert on numerical conformal mapping, so you might want to look at:

[http://www.amazon.com/Schwarz-Christoffel-Mapping-Tobin-Driscoll/dp/0521807263/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1295888442&sr=8-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521807263)